# Crosswalk errors trying to load Unity JNI libraries

Tags: android, cordova, unity-game-engine, ionic-framework, crosswalk

The following errors appear when my Android app is starting up:

```
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libmain.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(407)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libmain.so
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libxwalkdummy.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(407)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libxwalkdummy.so
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libmono.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(407)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libmono.so
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libxwalkcore.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(407)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libxwalkcore.so
I/chromium: [INFO:xwalk_extension_renderer_controller.cc(42)] EXTENSION PROCESS DISABLED.
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libVuforiaWrapper.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(407)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libVuforiaWrapper.so
W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app/com.myapp.app-1/lib/arm/libunity.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
```

libmain.so, libmono.so, libVuforiaWrapper.so, libunity.so are plattform specific libraries that are used when Unity is launched from my Cordova/Ionic application.

Why is Crosswalk loading (or attempting to load) these libraries? And what impact does not being able to load them have?

When I use crosswalk-lite, this case works fine, but I need full crosswalk because of other features in my app.

Comment: I have the same bug. Have you resolved it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android project with Unity JNI libraries crash after Crosswalk was added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045758/android-project-with-unity-jni-libraries-crash-after-crosswalk-was-added)